# Short Time Fourier Transform analysis of newborn baby cry signal

Tags: matlab

I am working on analysis of baby cry signal. fundamental frequency(Fo) of signal is already estimated using auto correlation and cepstrum analysis. cry signal is inputted in .wav format. now i want to do short time fourier transform analysis of same signal inorder to find variations in fundamental frequency over the time and plot its "pitch contour". i.e. Fo v/s t. its like finding Fo value for each small interval and plotting over time to see the variability. pls, can anybody help me with the matlab code?

Comment: What kind of help are you expecting if you don't share your code? This is no code-request forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SAaC](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/projects/SAcC/) from [LabROSA](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/). You also might be interested in [delta pitch without explicit pitch tracking](https://github.com/dpwe/pitchflow).

Comment: sir thank you for reply. it is helping me. but i am getting some errors in code which i tried from above site.

Comment: Make sure you've installed all dependencies and can run their examples first. Then try with your data. If it doesn't work post  new question with details and code as Matt says. Cheers.

Comment: sir @ruoho ruotsi , am using matlab 7.1 version. In one of the above code function "logfsgram(d,256,sr)" is used. here it gives error as "Undefined function 'logfsgram' for input arguments of type 'double' ". how to install these functions in my version?

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/dpwe/alignmidi/blob/master/logfsgram.m